# Move ball up and right

Tags: jquery, html, position

My previous program bounces a ball but now I want the user to be able to move it up and down, left and right whenever they want. So far my right and down buttons work but the logic for my left and up don't.

In my mind, the following code is correct but I guess it isn't

```
function moveU() {
    var currentTopPos = parseInt($("#ball").css('top'));
    // define the new position
    var newBottomPos = currentTopPos - velocity_y;

    if (newBottomPos >= maxTop || newBottomPos <= 0)
        velocity_y *= 0; // multiply the value by -1

    $("#ball").css('top', newBottomPos + 'px');
    maxTop = parseInt($("#outerbox").css('top')) - parseInt($("#outerbox").css('border-left-top')) - parseInt($("#ball").css('top'));
}
```

I currently have no errors. The ball simply doesn't move.

https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/4931/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.

---

Create a single `move` function, which moves the ball a given `x` or `y` amount, and then calls itself using a timer:

```
function move(x, y) {
  //movement code   
  moveBall= setTimeout(function() {
    move(x, y);
  },20);
}
```

---

You could then have a single function that handles all the movement buttons:

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
  $('.btn-primary').prop('disabled', false);
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  clearInterval(moveBall);
  switch(this.id) {
    case 'moveU': move(0, -velocity_y); break;
    case 'moveD': move(0,  velocity_y); break;
    case 'moveL': move(-velocity_x, 0); break;
    case 'moveR': move( velocity_x, 0); break;
  }
});
```

---

Instead of determining the current position of the ball and adding an offset, use jQuery's `css()` syntax for changing by a relative amount (`+=`):

```
$('#ball').css({
  top : '+=' + y,
  left: '+=' + x
});
```

---

If the ball is outside its container, simply reverse the relative direction (`-=`):

```
ofs= $('#ball').offset();

if(ofs.left < maxLeft || ofs.left+ballWidth  > maxRight ||
   ofs.top  < maxTop  || ofs.top +ballHeight > maxBottom
  ) {
  $('#ball').css({
    top : '-=' + y,
    left: '-=' + x
  });
}
```

---

I've put these suggestions together in this Fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/s1v128Lh/**

Comment: In jsfiddle your version works but when I implement it into mine it says the `Cannot read property 'left' of undefined` for ` maxLeft = $('#outerbox').offset().left + parseInt($("#outerbox").css('border-left-width')),`

Comment: If you can make a fiddle in which my code doesn't work, I'll troubleshoot.

Comment: well I fixed my error. But trying to get an understanding of how you use the .left with my current program... I think your version won't work. https://jsfiddle.net/pnuqyyqh/8/

Comment: My original program looked like this(2 sides worked) https://jsfiddle.net/pnuqyyqh/10/

Comment: In https://jsfiddle.net/pnuqyyqh/8/:  `clearInterval(move_ball_3)` doesn't do anything.  You probably want `setInterval`.  Also, `top : '-='+y,` and `left: '-='+x` won't work, because `x` and `y` are undefined.  In my code, they're set to 0 or one of the velocity variables like this:  `move(0, -velocity_y);`

Comment: Ok I will keep looking into moving the ball based on my current program.

Answer (score 0):

You changed too much: just copy, for example, moveR() and replace the plus with a minus:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/pnuqyyqh/

```
    function moveL() {
    // Read the current left position of the ball
    var currentLeftPos = parseInt($("#ball").css('left'));

    // define the new position
    var newLeftPos = currentLeftPos - velocity_x;

    // If the left position is greater than or equal to the maximum distance allowed or
    //   less than or equal to zero, then change the direction.

    if( newLeftPos >= maxLeft || newLeftPos <= 0)
        velocity_x *= 0; // multiply the value by -1

    // update the position
    $("#ball").css('left', newLeftPos + 'px');

    // display number of seconds played


  }
```

Comment: But, you might want to consider writing a general function for the movement that takes parameters for x and y movement anyway, so there is only one routine

Comment: I changed the - to a + as you suggested but it sends moveR ball to left when I do that and vise versa..

Comment: Note that I only said to COPY MoveR (meaning as a template for MoveL), and went on to give you the code for MoveL with the according minus sign. I changed nothing but the sign, which worked well in my fiddle.
My point about a general function (which was also raised by Rick Hitchcock in his answer) still stands and might be something to consider